# Linux Kernel Holding Packet?

Tags: networking, kernel, dns, socket, udp

I've been looking at a 3rd party program for DNS resolution (on an embedded solution) and in the code to send the DNS query to the upstream server it will connect() then send().

send() returns with the amount of bytes it was given (ie not -1 or errno set) but I never see the DNS query in Wireshark. So the DNS program thinks the packet was sent but never receives an response for it and times that packet out. Subsequent DNS queries go through with no problem though.

Is the kernel holding the packet and if so, how can I see WHY it might be doing this? There are no rules blocking the outbound of this packet.

I heard the kernel can hold a packet if it thinks the route to the remote destination is unreachable is this happening and if so, how do I find out more about that?

Comment: Are you sure to have the proper fltering in place in Wireshark to match what the application is doing? Can you change which nameserver the application uses?

Comment: I'm filtering on 'dns' traffic and I do not see the corresponding request to the first upstream server with Wireshark. The socket that is being used is set up for UDP, the IP of the nameserver, and port 53.